# What is the meaning of "width-in-height-out"?

Tags: flutter, documentation

I was reading Flutter docs, and I found a sentence:

> a specific layout protocol (e.g. whether the layout is ***width-in-height-out***, or ***constraint-in-size-out***, or whether the parent sets the size and position of the child before or after the child lays out, etc

Since I'm not a native English user and I've never seen expression like that, I cannot clearly understand the meaning of that phrase.
Does "width-in-height-out" mean "height gets constrained by width", or anything else?
And what about "constraint-in-size-out"?

Help me please :(

Comment: Can you include the link of the doc? And I think it is simply saying unbounded height issue, like you can have fixed/available width but infinite height. There are some widgets (`column, ListView,GridView ....`) take infinite height by default.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's very interesting video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUfXWzp0-DU&t=579s

In this video, the speaker says something like "Width-in Height-out is a common layout paradigm in Web (browser). You set the width constraint to be tight and set the height constraint to be loose. The parent specifies the width, then the child determines the height".